# vb.NET update statemend takes too long/never executes but executes in 1 sec from Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

I have a simple update statement that refuese to execute when passed from VB.NET (probably will after 10 minutes or so... haven't waited that long). But it executes in 1 sec from Oracle SQL Developer.

There are 67000 rows in table1

```
strQuery = "UPDATE table1 SET TYPE2 = TYPE2 || ', 5_badTag' WHERE LARGE = 'NO' AND ROUND = 'NO'"
SqlInsert = strQuery
cmdOleDbCommand = New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand(SqlInsert, dataAccessConn)
adpterODA.InsertCommand = cmdOleDbCommand
adpterODA.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Is there an open transaction on this table from another session (e.g. your SQL Developer)?

Comment: yes.... I'm so dumb. Thanks for the help!   edit: hmmm... cant find the button that says your answered it....

Comment: There's no way to flag a comment as an answer, you can answer it yourself if you like, or wait for someone to put that comment in an answer, or delete the question altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an open transaction on this table from another session (e.g. your SQL Developer)?